# How to update a tab opened with chrome.tabs.create({ url })

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a chrome extension and I want to open a tab with a button and with another button I want to refresh that page.
Currently I'm using an event listener on a button and I can open a local html page in a new tab. 
But I don't know how to refresh/update that specific page.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (){
    let shareButton = document.getElementById('focus');
    shareButton.addEventListener('click', function() { 
          chrome.tabs.create({ url: chrome.runtime.getURL("index.html") });
    });
});
```

Comment: You can save the tab id in a global variable (or in chrome.storage) inside chrome.tabs.create [callback](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create) but if this is inside the browserAction popup, it'll be closed automatically when you open a new tab in the same window.

Comment: My problem is that i want to create a sort of homepage of my extension. In the popup.html i want a button for open this homepage and with another button i want to  add data to that homepage. I don't really need to refresh that page. Maybe I'm totally in the wrong way with the method above.

Comment: That page can update itself in its own script, no need for the popup's second button.

Comment: Ok thank you. Now the problem is how I can pass data to that page? Can the variable in popup.js be shared with that page?

Comment: See [Modify a tab with an extension html file inside when opened from popup](//stackoverflow.com/a/54715122)

Answer (score 1):

To refresh that page or send data from the popup it's important that the popup isn't closed after opening the tab use the `active` property for this:

```
tab = chrome.tabs.create({ url, active: false })
```

afterwards you can refresh that tab or send a message:

```
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, data, responseReceived)
```